# index.rst build just only links of the rest of pages. - Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I have a index.rst with this sintaxis:

```
Example
======================================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 0 
   :caption: Contents:

   item 
Items and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

By other hand, I have a item.rst file with this:

```
Another page
======================================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 0 
   :caption: Contents:

   item2
```

What's the problem? I have an index with this:

[image]

But I do not want this. All content of item.rst (Another page) It should be displayed when I push in Another page not in the index.

I just want display in index the link of the rest of pages like this:

Contents:

- Another page
- Another second page
- Another third page.

Comment: Try `:maxdepth: 1`. I think 0 is the same as the default or infinite depth. Also add a blank line after `item` to separate it from the next section heading.

Comment: Thanks! That's works!

```:maxdepth: 1```